# Dandelion datatables not working on Liberty profile

Tags: websphere-liberty, dandelion

So I have this test application for simplistic sake. I have it working in Tomcat, but when I deploy the same war to a Liberty profile server it doesn't work. None of the bundleSources or ResourceScanner gets invoked.

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public DandelionDialect dandelionDialect()
    {
        return new DandelionDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataTablesDialect dataTablesDialect()
    {
        return new DataTablesDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter dandelionFilter()
    {
        return new DandelionFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean()
    {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new DandelionServlet(), "/dandelion-assets/*");
    }
}
```

com.github.dandelion=DEBUG
**Tomcat Logs** partial

```
2015-06-24 20:56:56.652  INFO 5964 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] com.github.dandelion.core.Context        : Selected asset cache system: default (based on MemoryAssetCache)
2015-06-24 20:56:56.657  INFO 5964 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] com.github.dandelion.core.Context        : Asset processor found: JsMinProcessor
2015-06-24 20:56:56.658  INFO 5964 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] com.github.dandelion.core.Context        : Asset processor found: CssMinProcessor
2015-06-24 20:56:56.662  INFO 5964 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] com.github.dandelion.core.Context        : Asset processor found: CssUrlRewritingProcessor
2015-06-24 20:56:56.662  INFO 5964 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] com.github.dandelion.core.Context        : Asset processors disabled. All assets will be left untouched.
2015-06-24 20:56:56.670 TRACE 5964 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : Scanning for resources at 'dandelion/vendor'...
```

and it continues to loading with Resource loader.

**Liberty logs**

```
2015-06-24 21:13:27.662  INFO 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] com.github.dandelion.core.Context        : Asset processors disabled. All assets will be left untouched.
2015-06-24 21:13:27.675 TRACE 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : Scanning for resources at 'dandelion/vendor'...
2015-06-24 21:13:27.678 TRACE 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : 0 resources found before filtering
2015-06-24 21:13:27.679 DEBUG 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : Filtering scanned resources
2015-06-24 21:13:27.679 DEBUG 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : 0 resources found after filtering
2015-06-24 21:13:27.679 DEBUG 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.c.b.l.impl.VendorBundleLoader      : 0 resources scanned inside the folder 'dandelion/vendor'. Parsing to bundle...
2015-06-24 21:13:27.680 TRACE 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : Scanning for resources at 'dandelion/datatables'...
2015-06-24 21:13:27.680 TRACE 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : 0 resources found before filtering
2015-06-24 21:13:27.681 DEBUG 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : Filtering scanned resources
2015-06-24 21:13:27.681 DEBUG 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : 0 resources found after filtering
2015-06-24 21:13:27.681 DEBUG 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.d.c.bundle.DatatablesBundleLoader  : 0 resources scanned inside the folder 'dandelion/datatables'. Parsing to bundle...
2015-06-24 21:13:27.682 TRACE 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : Scanning for resources at 'dandelion'...
2015-06-24 21:13:27.683 TRACE 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : 0 resources found before filtering
2015-06-24 21:13:27.683 DEBUG 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : Filtering scanned resources
2015-06-24 21:13:27.684 DEBUG 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.core.utils.ResourceScanner         : 0 resources found after filtering
2015-06-24 21:13:27.684 DEBUG 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.d.c.b.l.impl.DandelionBundleLoader   : 0 resources scanned inside the folder 'dandelion'. Parsing to bundle...
2015-06-24 21:13:27.684  INFO 8564 --- [ecutor-thread-9] c.g.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter   : Dandelion context initialized
```

None of the Resources are found why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue in the `ResourceScanner` class. Websphere application servers use a jar naming convention of wsjar. I created a fix here https://github.com/ohiocowboy/dandelion/tree/feat/liberty

Comment: Support for Websphere is added in the upcoming version (1.0.0). Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @tduchateau I saw that it was fixed in 1.0.0 before I did a modified 0.10.1. My application is probably being released to production before your release of 1.0.0. Do you have a target release date yet? Looking forward to the new code :)

Comment: It should be released by the end of the week :-)